# How to install D3D11 SDK Layers for Windows 10 offline

Tags: windows-10, direct3d, direct3d11

I got the following error when I was debugging my D3D application in VS2015.

```
D3D11CreateDevice: Flags (0x2) were specified which require the D3D11 SDK Layers for Windows 10, but they are not present on the system. These flags must be removed, or the Windows 10 SDK must be installed. Flags include: D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG
```

I know I need to enable Graphics Tools in Win10 or run `Dism /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Tools.Graphics.DirectX~~~~0.0.1.0` to enable it.

But the machine I am working on are not allowed to connect to the internet. Is there a way to enable that offline?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the November 2015 update (build 10586) of Windows 10, you can find the *Feature On Demand* CABs for the **Graphics Tools** package [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=620353). You can install it via `dism` as noted in the documentation with that package.

Keep in mind that there's a lot of stuff in Windows 10 that's a number of 'feature on demand' parts of Windows including .NET 3.5, language packs, etc.

Comment: Thank you Chuck. Works like a charm. I was just looking for something like this. Just one more question, is there an index page for these packages? Just in case you know.

Comment: The package link above is a workaround for the Hardware Logo Kit. You can also get the FOD CABs as an MSDN or TechNet Subscriber.

Comment: I have uninstalled both x86 and x64 package from system as well as removed them but still I can see the error log in VS 2017 IDE console. I wanted to remove the Graphics Tool and don't want to debug anything. But it still looking for the flag even if the flag is not added in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe the Graphic tools can ben installed from the iso of your Win10 ?

Comment: I thought about it, actually I installed .Net Framework 3.5 from the iso using `dism` commands I found on the internet. But I can't find anything about how to do that for the Graphic Tools.

Comment: Have you tried to install the Graphic Tools on another computer, then copy the corresponding folders from c:/Windows/WinSxs ? I have these files and folders : amd64_microsoft-windows-directx-graphics-tools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_37bf9082f6de1fcf, x86_microsoft-windows-directx-graphics-tools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_dba0f4ff3e80ae99, amd64_microsoft-windows-directx-graphics-tools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_37bf9082f6de1fcf.manifest and x86_microsoft-windows-directx-graphics-tools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_dba0f4ff3e80ae99.manifest.