# DirectX 11 debugger requires Windows SDK 10 but it's selected in IDE and present in system

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, visual-studio-debugging, directx-11

While working with directx11 APIs I frequently getting a warning stated below but I can see Windows SDK 10 is present in the system (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools) as well as selected that version in VS IDE.

> D3D11CreateDevice: Flags (0x2) were specified which require the D3D11 SDK Layers for Windows 10, but they are not present on the system.
>   These flags must be removed, or the Windows 10 SDK must be installed.
>   Flags include: D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG

I have to debug directx11 objects. I need to get rid from that warning. Would anyone please help to fix this issue?

**FIX**: Graphics Tools installed offline following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318515/how-to-install-d3d11-sdk-layers-for-windows-10-offline) and the warning is gone.

But now it throws exception from D3D11CreateDevice() but the flag D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG is added or not it throws following exception. How to fix this exception?

> Exception thrown at 0x27A7DD55 (d3d11_3SDKLayers.dll) in xxx.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Also, what is your code calling ``D3D11CreateDevice``.  See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1803

Comment: So you have installed the _Graphics Tools_ which was your original issue--without it you don't have the debug device installed--, but you can still have bugs in your code. What does your code for calling ``D3D11CreateDevice`` look like because that's what's probably wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uninstalled then installed the Graphics Tools again. Then followed the your [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/) then it showed debug layer outputs. I can see DXGI error and warnings now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*D3D11CreateDevice: Flags (0x2) were specified which require the D3D11 SDK Layers for Windows 10, but they are not present on the system. These flags must be removed, or the Windows 10 SDK must be installed. Flags include: D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG*

This issue was encountered during a Qt Multimedia widget development and it has been resolved by following steps,

1. Updated intel graphic drivers - Refer this for more details https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005629/graphics.html
2. Created the device to support the debug layer. Follow this for Windows 10 & 11,
   Go to the Settings panel -> under System -> Apps & features -> Manage optional Features -> Add a feature, and then look for "Graphics Tools" & install.
3. Finally reboot the system & try.