# Get D3D debug information?

Tags: windows-10, direct3d, direct3d11

during initialisation of my D3D stuff, I call the following function:

```
        hr = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr,gDriverTypes[DriverTypeIndex],nullptr,
#ifdef _DEBUG
            D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG,
#else
            0,
#endif
            gFeatureLevels,gNumFeatureLevels,D3D11_SDK_VERSION,&lDevice,&lFeatureLevel,&lImmediateContext);
```

In debug build, to get additional information about possible D3D errors, I set the flag D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG. Without any further actions this lets my application terminate immediately.

So according to [Use D3D11 debug layer with VS2013 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809169/use-d3d11-debug-layer-with-vs2013-on-windows-10/32828880) I tried to install the required D3D-debug stuff by calling

```
Dism /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Tools.Graphics.DirectX~~~~0.0.1.0
```

within a admin-console on latest windows 10. Unfortunately this fails with

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1316
Image Version: 10.0.18363.1316
[==========================100.0%==========================]
Error: 0x8024500c
DISM failed. No operation was performed.
```

The log file is also not very helpful, it contains loads of error messages and error codes one can't understand easily.

So...are there alternative ways to get the D3D debug stuff that is required to work with D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG enabled?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, support for the Direct3D 11 and Direct3D 12 "Debug Device" is only available with the "Graphics Tools" Windows optional feature enabled.

The HRESULT of `0x8024500c` indicates you have some problem with Windows Update on your system. It's `WU_E_REDIRECTOR_CONNECT_POLICY`.

Most likely your PC is on a corporate network using WSUS. You need to ask the IT admins to allow this Windows optional feature.